# How to retrieve values from node js to html without making an ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, ajax

I'm passing form datas into nodejs using form action attribute & retrieving it. The thing is I can retrieve the datas from nodejs using ajax call. But my requirement says like should not make ajax call. Can anyone please guide me please?

Comment: Retrieve the data on the server *before* you render the page, or make a standard page request to get the information in the next page. There's no alternative without AJAX.

Comment: So what templating engine are you using to render the content from your node.js server?

Comment: I'm using html @icepickle

Comment: Pure html? There is no [tag:express] server behind it, or something similar

Comment: yes it is html & we are using express server. @Icepickle